# How to remove custom suffix after file extension in Windows via script?

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd

I have a folder full of CSV files which get stored with a time stamp and an identifier after the file type, meaning Windows does not recognize the files as CSVs (and any VBA code to access them won't recognize them either).

The file format is always: `ABCDEFG.csv.20161205-071658`

`ABCDEFG.csv` never changes.

How do I remove all characters after the second `.`?

Comment: VBA code (or any other code for that matter) will not care about the file extension if written not do so ...

Comment: What do you want to actually do? if "ABCDEFG.csv" is really always the same then you can't remove the extension as they exist on disk as you would have name collisions.  One obvious thing is to rename to *.csv to put another .csv on the end whilst preserving unique names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following batch file could be used to get the file `ABCDEFG.csv.20161205-071658` renamed to `ABCDEFG_20161205-071658.csv` in folder `C:\Temp` as well as all other non hidden files matching the pattern `*.csv.*`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%I in ("C:\Temp\*.csv.*") do (
    for %%J in ("%%~nI") do (
        set "DateTime=%%~xI"
        set "DateTime=!DateTime:~1!"
        ren "%%I" "%%~nJ_!DateTime!%%~xJ"
    )
)
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Thank you so much, works a charm! Sorry for the late response